# appium and genymotion multiple device errors

Tags: appium, adb, genymotion

I want to manage my android devices using Appium and Genymotion.

I get an error when 2 devices are active at the same time, the error output is;

[image]

But after turning off one of the 2 devices, I can connect to the active device. The only problem is that when 2 devices are active at the same time, I cannot connect to any of them.

Capability:

[image]

adb devices:

[image]

I tried changing the port but I guess genymotion ports don't change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

You can avoid the error by giving different ports to each emulator adb.

Required Code:
`adb -s [EMULATOR_UDID] forward tcp:5556 tcp:5555`